# How to securely communicate with a device behind a router?

Tags: networking, router, security

Networking noob here.

I want to find a secure way to communicate with a device that is located behind a router ([Teltonika RUT950](https://teltonika-networks.com/product/rut950/)). The router has a fixed public IP. The device that is connected to the router has no authentication feature. Anyone in the local network can communicate with it (over the Modbus TCP protocol).

I want to be able to communicate with the device securely from an external server (the server could have a dedicated IP if needed).

The simplest option that comes to my mind is to set a port forwarding on the router, restricting the source to the IP of the external server. However I'm aware this solution is vulnerable to IP spoofing attacks.

What other options do I have to secure the communication?

**Edit**
Adding more details as the actual problem is more complex and the proposed solution covers the original simplified scenario:

In summary the external server needs to query multiple devices, each behind a separate router. The server needs to query each device once every few seconds. There is around 50 devices to query and the list will grow over time.

[image]

Comment: TCP is generally not susceptible to IP spoofing.

Comment: @Barmar how so?

Comment: Because of its bidirectional nature. In order to complete the TCP handshake, the spoofer needs to receive the response from the target. But the response will go to the IP that was spoofed, not the spoofer.

Answer (score 3):

The most secure way of doing what you want to achieve would be to use another device such as a Raspberry PI in your local network, set up a vpn e.g. with OpenVPN and then connect a VPN client from your remote computer to the running server on the PI.

With this solution, you now have a secure connection that needs an authentication, so you only will be able to "get into your secure LAN behind the Teltonika router" if you know the correct user/password combination registered in the VPN-Server on the PI. Doing it this way means that you do not need to get a static IP address for your remote computer and spoofing the connection is nearly impossible.

---

Edit concerning this specific model of a router:
This model already includes a configurable OpenVPN server. With it you can save the work and money for the proposed solution with a Raspberry PI and directly connect to the router via a VPN. In the [manual](https://wiki.teltonika-networks.com/view/RUT950_VPN#OpenVPN) there is a brief explanation, but if you look around the web administration panel of the router you will most likely find the VPN option quite quickly. I do not know this specific model myself, but in most control panels the option for remote access using a VPN and the settings for port forwarding are in the same category.

Comment: According to the [manual](https://wiki.teltonika-networks.com/view/RUT950_VPN#OpenVPN) the router supports OpenVPN, so it might be possible to setup a tunnel from the external server straight to the router without needing additional hardware.

Comment: @VL-80 Well, then this is much easier. I did not look up the specific router, so if it is ok for you, I will include this in the answer.

Comment: Of course, go ahead and add it to your answer.

Comment: Yes, the router allows to set up VPN. In fact it is already configured. However there is a twist to the story. The external server needs to read data every few seconds from multiple sites with the similar setup (router + the device behind it, each with a separate VPN configured). I suppose if I wanted to use VPN connection for that it could provide other challenges (like IP conflicts when multiple VPNs connected at the same time, or time lag if keeping single VPN enabled at a time and switching  every few seconds)

Comment: @mrt Yes, your are right if you want to read from multiple devices in different networks, you will need to configure different IP-ranges for the different networks. But then you should be able to configure the client on the server to only use the VPN connection for the specific IP addresses of the devices, and this should be a solution for lag and other problems

Comment: That could work, however I will not have the guarantee the VPNs will use non conflicting IP ranges. The configuration of those networks is outside of my control. Additionally, new networks that I will have to speak to will be added periodically and if I make the solution dependent on the internal IP range of VPN I'm opening the system to 'malfunctions' caused by external factors. I would very much like to avoid it.

Comment: I've thought about this problem once again, and there is another possible solution: Instead of trying to fetch the data using your server, can you just send the data to it? Use a RasPI or something like it inside the secure networks that fetches the data over the LAN and then packages it securely encrypted to send it to the server. Like this it is encrypted before it leaves the secure LAN.